# Framework Laravel: view records using specific condition

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have never learnt this framework. As a beginner, I have to modify/add a link in the existing software which is made by some professional team. Could you people can help me out of this situation?

There is a function that shows the records on the main page `public function index()`. It has `return View::make('Titles.Index')->withType('movie');`. But I have to add a parameter that shows only english movies having field name `language` can have 'en' as its value. Would you suggest what needs to be done that it will show up using this condition? I have tried `return View::make('Titles.Index')->with('language','en');` but it shows error on the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, **index** is a controller method that handles the view for your specific route.

Inside the controller method, you can filter the movies and pass a collection to the view. Considering that you have a model called `Movie` with namespace `App\Movie` so you can do something like:

```
public function index() {
  // Returns a collection with movies where language field 
  // is equal 'en'.
  $moviesEn = App\Movie::where('language', 'en')->get();
  return View::make('Titles.Index')->with('moviesEn', $moviesEn);
}
```

This code injects the `moviesEn` variable inside your `Titles.Index` view. So there you can use it:

```
@foreach ($moviesEn as $movie)
  {{ $movie->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: return View::make('Titles.Index')->with('moviesEn', $moviesEn); When I do this, page shows an error that something went wrong. When i write return View::make('Titles.Index')->with('type','movie'); it displays the rows where type is movie in the table, but it doesn't work where language is en in the same table.

Comment: Just am puzzled why it works with the field name 'type' and doesn't work with the field name 'language' of the same table!

Comment: Your answer helped me finally I could manage it. Thanks a lot Alexandre!